# Could R use source() to avoid the variable to be replaced?

Tags: r

Here is my temp.R

```
a=1
print(a)
```

but when i use source("temp.R") the variable a is replaced

```
> a=3
> source("temp.R")
[1] 1
> a
[1] 1
```

And my expectation is that

```
> a=3
> source("temp.R")
[1] 1
> a
[1] 3
```

Could this be done in R?
Any help to get the result as described above would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluate the expression within its own environment:

```
# write out the file to be sourced
fLS = file(description = "Code/8-LocalSource-Input.R", open = "w+")
write(x ="a = 1; print(a)", file = fLS)
close(fLS)

# source the file
a = 3
sourceEnv = new.env()
with(sourceEnv, source("Code//8-LocalSource-Input.R", local = TRUE))
a
```